# Prevent SQL injection by restricting characters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Is it OK to say that by restricting this symbol, we restrict SQL injection.

1. '(quotation)
2. "(double quotation)
3. ;(semicolon)

Because as far as I know most SQL injections are by closing an input by putting quotation or double quotation in the beginning and then close the sentence by semicolon .

Please help me out if its true. And if its not true please provide me an example that how without using these characters injection is possible .

Comment: "Is it OK to say that by restricting this symbol, we restrict SQL injection." --- it's totally not.

Comment: Consider that I put all of my input in single or double quotation. So in below example id="" . So it needs to use " first to close the input and then do what we want to do. So by restricting " injection is not possible i thing . lets say that injection is would be : " or 1=1 --

Comment: What is the reason you prefer this solution over the one that is proven to work? Like, what drives you to deliberately weaken your application security?

Comment: I am scrutinizing vulnerability of MySQL command and it became a question to me how it could be possible to inject if the condition is like I described.

Comment: Why don't you check any answer then? The most upvoted one demonstrates how you could be injected (as per the question limitations).

Answer (score 2):

The SQL injection can be prevented by using PDO. You have to escape the inputs and sanitize it. 
For Example you have query:

```
Select col1 from table where id=$input_from_user
```

Now see if user input is 12 or 1==1, and you directly out it in query. The query will always return result.

PDO's can prevent such attack.

Answer (score 1):

I like this one, it slips thru your check:

`?id=13 UNION SELECT 1,user(),3,4,5,6,7`

Why bother with the `<FORM>`, just jam it into the url.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the mysql syntax, that's why I given example based on sqlserver, so don't give minus for this.

Yes, this will sufficient, but still there is some other reserved work will cause issue like '&', '<', '>' for xml field or xml manipulation.

Sql injection is work when we use inline query as (For this reason always use procedure to avoid sql injection)

```
Declare @var1 nvarchar(100) = 'column 1 like ''' + 'abc' + '%' -- suppose this will also pass from your c# or vb.net or java code as ("column1 like 'abc'")

Declare @strsql nvarchar(500) 
@strsql = 'Select * from table where ' + @var1

exec @strsql
```

If you give value as sql injection as the above value will return everything even user does not have rights : 1=1 --

```
Declare @strsql nvarchar(500) 
@strsql = 'Select * from table where 1=1--' 

exec @strsql -- the sql injection will remove your all succeeding value
```